# Отсиртировать Vec<(String, u64)>

Tags: сортировка, rust

Есть вектор такого вида:

```
vec![("a", 10), ("c", 100), ("b", 50)]
```

Как можно отсортировать его по второму элементу tuple?

```
vec![("a", 10), ("b", 50), ("c", 100)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sort_by_key](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort_by_key)

```rust
fn main() {
  let mut v = vec![("a", 10), ("c", 100), ("b", 50)];
  v.sort_by_key(|i| i.1);
  println!("{:?}", v);
}
```